# Flutter video_player is taking too much time to load video from firbase

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-video-player

Hi I am creating a video player which lists all videos from Firebase storage and play it. I used cache_video_player plugin to play video. This is similar to video_player plugin with cache service. This plugin takes too much time to initialize and load video from network(approximately 10-20 seconds). Is there any way to reduce loading time of this plugin or is there any other plugin which takes minimum time to load video from network

Answer (score 2):

Basically [cached_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_video_player) plugin is virtually a clone of official [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin. I used video_player plugin in my project and it takes time when initializing and loading the video when playing from network, it works fine when playing a local video as a file but takes time for playing video from network. It totally depends upon your internet connection and speed, No need to worry about and I don't think that you will find any better plugin for playing video other than video_player.

Comment: is it problem with firebase storage . It is take less time to load video from github.